# Populate dropDownList from a JSon Array

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I am trying to populate a dropDownList based on a JSON Array that i get from a webservice.

Here is an example of the Json Array that I get:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"AJ Shaw"},{"id":2,"name":"Jay Black"}]
```

Here is my javascript that I am using to try and load the dropDownList

```
function load_level1() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("/facility/getTaxLevel1_LOV")%>',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            method: "GET",
            success: function (Result) {
                $.each(Result, function(key, value) {
                    $("#level1").append($("<option></option>").val
                        (value).html(value));
                });
            },
            error: function (Result) {
                alert("Error");
            },
            failure: function (Result) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my dropDownList object:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="level1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" ><asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Select Level 1" ></asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
```

I just want to populate a dropDownList with an Id, and name.  It can't be that hard, but I am lost.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `<asp:DrownDownList>` is a server-side component. Is it possible to load the items on the server, rather than on the client (through AJAX)?

Answer (score 0):

try this in success function ajax request

```
$.each(Result,function(key,value){ 
  $("#level1").append($("<option></option>").val(value.id).html(value.name));
});
```

Comment: It is still not populating my dropDownList.  Looking in the Chrome Debugger i am getting some message about "jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1047' in [{"id":1,"name":.....}]

Comment: verify in your json has no invalid characters. Try do execute this code down.

`$.each([{"id":1,"name":"AJ Shaw"},{"id":2,"name":"Jay Black"}],function(key,value){    console.log(value.name) });`